# How to plot multiple yearly data in one graph

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, date-and-time

There is a dataset: for each year a single data for 6 seas. I would like to have a graph to visualize paralel changes.

This is what I attempted to reproduce
http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/daviz/annual-average-sea-surface-temperature-1#tab-chart_1

I imported tsv file, made some corrections.

[image]

ListPlot looks almost nice, but on x-axis I have only natural numbers, not the years.

I also tried DateListPlot, but it did not accept just years.

```
datedata = 
 Map[Rest, 
   Rest@SST] /. {a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_, 
    g_} -> {{a, b}, {a, c}, {a, d}, {a, e}, {a, f}, {a, g}}

{{{1870, -0.59}, {1870, -0.53}, {1870, -0.33}, {1870, -0.44}, {1870, 
-0.43}, {1870, -0.59}}, {{1871, -0.6}, {1871, -0.57}, {1871, -0.33}, 
{1871, -0.47}, {1871, -0.43}, {1871, -0.56}}, {{1872, -0.58}, {1872, 
-0.65}, {1872, -0.34}, {1872, -0.5}, {1872, -0.41}, {1872, -0.55}}, 
{{1873, -0.55}, {1873, -0.62}, {1873, -0.3}, {1873, -0.45}, {1873, 
-0.39}, {1873, -0.5}}, ...
```

Inserting some fake month and day still not helped.

```
data[[1]]

{{{1870, 1, 1}, -0.59}, {{1870, 1, 1}, -0.53}, {{1870, 1, 
   1}, -0.33}, {{1870, 1, 1}, -0.44}, {{1870, 1, 1}, -0.43}, {{1870, 
   1, 1}, -0.59}}
```

[image]

Comment: The format for `ListPlot` is `{{x,y},{x,y},{x,y}...}`. `x` in your case is the year corresponding to the measured anomaly `y`. For example plotting the list in your code block will actually work - if you plot that the year will appear on the x axis.

Comment: I've already tried, but it ruins coloring

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data = Import["http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/daviz/annual-average-sea-surface-temperature-1/download.csv"];
```

Process the imported data to remove the first (empty) column and the first (header) row, and separate column 1 from the rest:

```
{times, states} = {#[[All, 1]], #[[All, 2 ;;]]} &@Rest[Rest /@ data];

labels = {"Global ocean", "Baltic Sea", "North Atlantic", "North Sea",
"Mediterranean Sea", "Black Sea"};
```

Create a `TemporalData` object using `times` and `states`:

```
td = TemporalData[states, {times}];
```

**Using `ListPlot`:**

```
ListPlot[td, PlotLegends ->labels, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Alternatives:

```
ListPlot[Transpose@states, DataRange -> Through@{Min, Max}@times, 
 PlotLegends -> labels, ImageSize -> 500]
(* same picture *)
```

Or, create six series of `{date, value}` pairs:

```
datab = Rest[Rest /@ data][[All, {1, #}]] & /@ Range[2, 7];
ListPlot[datab, PlotLegends -> labels, ImageSize -> 500]
(* also same picture *)
```

**Using `DateListPlot`:**

```
DateListPlot[Transpose@states, {Min@times}, PlotLegends -> labels, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Alternatively, turn `{date, value}` pairs in `datab` into `{{date}, value}` pairs:

```
datac = datab;
datac[[All, All, 1]] = List /@ # & /@ datab[[All, All, 1]];
DateListPlot[datac, PlotLegends -> labels, ImageSize -> 500]
(* same picture *)
```